# Need a design suggestion for implementing animation in android app

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, gif

I have an activity with a viewpager in full screen. now, what i want is that when are more pages to be seen, an animated arrow will slide down from the top of the screen and stay presented there. the arrow will disappear only when touched or moving to other page (if you move to other page and then return to the current, the arrow will not be present). any suggestion on how to implement this?
my current strategy: 1. making a gif with the animation of the arrow sliding down. 2. when message received, dynamically attach the arrow to the top of the current fragment presented on the screen. make the gif repeat only once. 3. dynamically remove the arrow when the user swipe to other page.

things that i don't sure if they are possible: is it possible to play the gif only once? is it possible to attach a view dynamically to the current fragment? is it possible to remove the view when the current fragment is out?

i would be glad if you could tell me if my strategy is right and if every step is possible, before I'm going to crack my head in google on how to actually implement it:)

it needs to look like this: arrow is sliding from the top (half way down): 
arrow is sliding from the top (half way down):
[image]

arrow reach his final position:
[image]

Comment: You should try ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok after lots of reading I finally implemented like this:
1. I created a button and attach it dynamicaly.
2. I set an animation for the button so it will slide down from top.
3. I set click listener to remove the button.
4. I set an setOnPageChangeListener on the viewPager that removes the button on page change.

1. I added a method called "attachbutton()" to the fragment class:
   (from some reason i can't put the first part as "code"...)

   LayoutInflater inflater =
                   (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           this.button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.new_message_button);
           if (this.button == null) {

   ```
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_messages_button, rootView, true);
       this.button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.new_message_button);
       this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               mPager.setCurrentItem(lastPage);

           }
       });

        this.button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_in_top));

            this.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

   }
   ```

and this is the xml of the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        />

</set>
```

and this is the listener of the viewPager:

```
 mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                currentFragment.removeButton();
                mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
            }

        });
```